# Joule's free expansion expreiment: where is system?

Tags: thermodynamics

everyone.

I have some cofusions in Joule's ideal gas free expansion, especially in aspect of 1st law of thermodynamics.

In various textbook(Kerson Huang, Merhan Kardar) they suggests that there is no work, no heat exchange during the expansion. This leads to useful relationships about the ideal gas like linearity of internal energy and temperature.

But before that, it is necessary to specify where is system to consider.

1. If system contains (1), (2) both: the system's initial temperature have two phase; in (2) region where perfect vacuum is assumed, temperature should be zero according to kinetic theory approach.
2. If system contains (1) only: no volume change, N (particle #) changes, then no practical results.
3. If system contains (1) only, but after expansion (1), (2) both: before expansion, surrounding should contain (2). Then surrounding has phases as case 1. Does constant surrounding temperature except (2) guarantee no heat exchange?

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion]

Well, this might be simple problem to someone else, but really puzzle to me. In summary, I want to know which system definition can explain this experiment as the textbooks do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A system can be what is in an enclosure but does not have to include the enclosure.

So in your example the contents (the system) of the $V_{\rm i}$ enclosure expand into a bigger enclosure with volume $V_{\rm f}$.
If the enclosure does not allow the transfer of heat then all that is happening is that after expansion the ideal gas molecules (the system) are on average further apart.
As there are no intermolecular forces acting no work needs to be done to separate the molecules so their velocity (kinetic energy) distribution does not change.

Answer (score 1):

Choice 1 is correct. The system consists of the contents of the rigid insulated container.  In this case, if there is vacuum in 2, then the initial internal energy in 2 is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The *system* can be defined in any way you choose. Thus you can define the system as (1), (2), or (1) plus (2).  But once you do, everything not included in the system constitutes the *surroundings*. Moreover, what separates the system from the surroundings is then, by definition, the *boundary*. That boundary can be real or imaginary, open or closed, fixed or (re)moveable.

That said, with regard to your three statements (where an ideal gas is assumed):

(1) I agree with this statement. What’s more this is the system that, as you say, is described in the textbooks.

(2) Since you say the volume does not change, it sounds like you are defining the system to be restricted to the region in space in the left compartment minus its contents (gas), since most certainly the volume of the gas does change. But to consider the compartment, which is really a boundary, and not the gas as the system would seem to be be meaningless.

To be meaningful, you can consider the gas that is only within the left compartment as the system. Then compartment 2, and everything outside the two compartments, are the surroundings. Moreover you now have an open system since mass of the system transfers to part of the surroundings (compartment 2) upon removal of the partition.

(3) After the expansion into compartment 2 mass of the system becomes half of the original. The other half occupies part of the surroundings (compartment 2). Since compartments 1 and 2 together are isolated from the remainder of the surroundings, the total internal energy of the system plus compartment 2 must be the same as the original internal energy of system (compartment 1).

But now you have half the original internal energy in the system. But since the system has half the original number of particles, *the energy per particle is the same.*  And since the system is an ideal gas, where all the energy is kinetic for an ideal gas, the temperature of the system is unchanged.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The "system" is an invention of the observer for the purposes of analyzing a physical situation. We should be able to solve a problem under various definitions of the system, although some make the solution easier than others.

There are more choices than the ones you mention. Take the volume occupied by the gas to be system $A$ and the the rest of the box system $B$. Some would call $A$ the "system" and $B$ the "surroundings", but this is semantics. In this view system $A$ goes from volume $V_1$ to $V_1+V_2$ at constant energy, and system $B$ goes from volume $V_2$ to $0$, also at constant energy, which in this case is zero. For the *combined* system $A$ plus $B$, the energy balance gives
$$
   (U_A+U_B)_\text{before} =  (U_A+U_B)_\text{after}
   \\\Rightarrow \\ 
   U(T_1,V_1,N_1) = U(T_2,V_1+V_2,N_1)
$$
This is the equation we solve for $T_2$.